# How to obtain the quantization of a simple pendulum using Bohr-Wilson-Sommerfeld rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, oscillators, semiclassical

How to obtain the quantization of a simple pendulum using  Bohr-Wilson-Sommerfeld rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bohr–Sommerfeld quantization condition states that only the motions that obey the quantization condition are allowed:

$$\oint\limits_{H(p,q)=E} p_i \, dq_i = n_i h$$

You should start by taking the Hamiltonian of your system and isolating the momentum:

$$\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}kx^2=E$$

Next, you should calculate the integral in the first equation. The path you must consider to calculate the integral is the path that a classical particle would follow. For a 1D pendulum, this would be an oscilation from $-a$ to $a$, and back to $-a$, where $a$ is the amplitude of the oscillation (you can claculate $a$ using the conservation of energy).

I think that you should be able to finish the problem with this help. If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask them.